# Using Jackson to extract information from Property names

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I currently receive the following JSON body

```json
{
    "productId": "90000011",
    "offerId": "String",
    "format": "String",
    "sellerId": "String",
    "sellerName": "String",
    "shippingPrice[zone=BE,method=STD]": 0.0,
    "deliveryTimeEarliestDays[zone=BE,method=STD]": 1,
    "deliveryTimeLatestDays[zone=BE,method=STD]": 1,
    "shippingPrice[zone=NL,method=STD]": 0.0,
    "deliveryTimeEarliestDays[zone=NL,method=STD]": 1,
    "deliveryTimeLatestDays[zone=NL,method=STD]": 1
}
```

As you can see, I have similar properties that differ by `zone` and `method` enclosed in square brackets. I don't want to change the code every time a new `zone` and/or `method` is introduced. I'm looking for a more dynamic way you deserialize this via Jackson.

Is there a way to automatically deserialize all properties starting with `shippingPrice`, `deliveryTimeEarliestDays` and `deliveryTimeLatestDays` into the following format?

```json
{
    "productId": "90000011",
    "offerId": "String",
    "format": "String",
    "sellerId": "String",
    "sellerName": "String",
    "deliveryModes":[
    {
        "method":"STD"
        "zone":"BE",
        "shippingPrice":0.0,
        "deliveryTimeEarliestDays":1,
        "deliveryTimeLatestDays":1
    },{
        "method":"STD"
        "zone":"NL",
        "shippingPrice":0.0,
        "deliveryTimeEarliestDays":1,
        "deliveryTimeLatestDays":1
    }]
}
```

My first idea was to use the `@JsonAnySetter` annotation and put everything in a `Map` but that still leaves me with manual parsing of the field name.

My Second Idea was to [build a custom deserializer](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization) where I loop over all attributes and filter out all the ones that start with `shippingPrice`, `deliveryTimeEarliestDays` and `deliveryTimeLatestDays` and map them to the described format above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve the required result, you need to implement deserialization logic yourself, it can't be done only by sprinkling a couple of data binding annotations.

That's how it can be done.

Assume here's a POJO that corresponds to your input JSON (*to avoid boilerplate code, I'll use Lombok annotations*):

```
@Getter
@Setter
public static class MyPojo {
    private String productId;
    private String offerId;
    private String format;
    private String sellerId;
    private String sellerName;
    @JsonIgnore // we don't want to expose this field to Jackson as is
    private Map<DeliveryZoneMethod, DeliveryMode> deliveryModes = new HashMap<>();
    
    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setDeliveryModes(String property, String value) {
        DeliveryZoneMethod zoneMethod = DeliveryZoneMethod.parse(property);
        DeliveryMode mode = deliveryModes.computeIfAbsent(zoneMethod, DeliveryMode::new);
        
        String name = property.substring(0, property.indexOf('['));

        switch (name) {
            case "shippingPrice" -> mode.setShippingPrice(new BigDecimal(value));
            case "deliveryTimeEarliestDays" -> mode.setDeliveryTimeEarliestDays(Integer.parseInt(value));
            case "deliveryTimeLatestDays" -> mode.setDeliveryTimeLatestDays(Integer.parseInt(value));
        }
    }
    
    public Collection<DeliveryMode> getModes() {
        return deliveryModes.values();
    }
}
```

Properties `productId`, `offerId`, `format`, `sellerId`, `sellerName` would be parsed by Jackson in a regular way.

And all other properties formatted like `"shippingPrice[zone=BE,method=STD]"` would be handled by the method annotated with `@JsonAnySetter`.

To facilitate extracting and storing information from such properties I've defined a couple of auxiliary classes:

- `DeliveryZoneMethod` which contains information about a zone and delivery method as its name suggests (the purpose of this class is to serve as *Key* in the map `deliveryModes`).
- `DeliveryMode` which is meant to contain all the need information that correspond to a particular zone and method of delivery.

For conciseness, `DeliveryZoneMethod` can be implemented as a Java 16 record:

```
public record DeliveryZoneMethod(String method, String zone) {
    public static Pattern ZONE_METHOD = Pattern.compile(".+zone=(\\p{Alpha}+).*method=(\\p{Alpha}+)");
    public static DeliveryZoneMethod parse(String str) {
        // "shippingPrice[zone=BE,method=STD]" - assuming the given string has always the same format
        Matcher m = ZONE_METHOD.matcher(str);
        
        if (!m.find()) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to parse: " + str);
        
        return new DeliveryZoneMethod(m.group(1), m.group(2));
    }
}
```

And here's how `DeliveryMode` might look like:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public static class DeliveryMode {
    private String method;
    private String zone;
    private BigDecimal shippingPrice;
    private int deliveryTimeEarliestDays;
    private int deliveryTimeLatestDays;
    
    public DeliveryMode(DeliveryZoneMethod zoneMethod) {
        this.method = zoneMethod.method();
        this.zone = zoneMethod.zone();
    }
}
```

*Usage example:*

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    String json = """
        {
            "productId": "90000011",
            "offerId": "String",
            "format": "String",
            "sellerId": "String",
            "sellerName": "String",
            "shippingPrice[zone=BE,method=STD]": 0.0,
            "deliveryTimeEarliestDays[zone=BE,method=STD]": 1,
            "deliveryTimeLatestDays[zone=BE,method=STD]": 1,
            "shippingPrice[zone=NL,method=STD]": 0.0,
            "deliveryTimeEarliestDays[zone=NL,method=STD]": 1,
            "deliveryTimeLatestDays[zone=NL,method=STD]": 1
        }
        """;
    
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    MyPojo myPojo = mapper.readValue(json,  MyPojo.class);

    String serializedJson = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(myPojo);
    
    System.out.println(serializedJson);
}
```

*Output:*

```
{
  "productId" : "90000011",
  "offerId" : "String",
  "format" : "String",
  "sellerId" : "String",
  "sellerName" : "String",
  "modes" : [ {
    "method" : "BE",
    "zone" : "STD",
    "shippingPrice" : 0.0,
    "deliveryTimeEarliestDays" : 1,
    "deliveryTimeLatestDays" : 1
  }, {
    "method" : "NL",
    "zone" : "STD",
    "shippingPrice" : 0.0,
    "deliveryTimeEarliestDays" : 1,
    "deliveryTimeLatestDays" : 1
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this well-documented answer! This was indeed what I was looking for. You even covered the part where I don't need to take the other fields into the deserialization but only the custom fields. One more question. What will happen now with other unknown attributes? I assume they will just be ignored or can you have a second @JsonAnySetter?

Comment: @GlennVanSchil It's not allowed to have more than one method annotated with `@JsonAnySetter` (*because Jackson would not be able to find out which to use when*). If you need a separate logical branch of for properties that are not formatted as `"foo[zone=BAR,method=BAZ]"`, then you need to place it into the same method. For instance, you can check the property name against a regular expression to decide how to handle it.

Comment: @GlennVanSchil You can introduce as many logical branches for handling the input as you need. In such scenario, I would advise declaring a separate method implementing the logic of each branch. And the method marked with `@JsonAnySetter` would perform delegating calls to these methods. You can also define more than one Map, but there should be only one method annotated with `@JsonAnySetter`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, makes sense. Thank you for your time and answers!

Answer (score 0):

I would go with your first idea to deserialize your JSON into a map. And yes you will still need to analyze the map keys. It is easy to deserialize Json into a map with Json Jackson, but there is an Open source library called MgntUtils that provides class `JsonUtils` which is a thin wrapper over Json-Jackson library. using it you can very simply deserialize your Json into a Map (or any other class). Your code would look like this:

```
try {
            Map<String, Object> map = JsonUtils.readObjectFromJsonString(jsonStr, Map.class);
            System.out.println(map);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      ...
    }
```

Here is Javadoc for [JsonUtils](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html). The library can be obtained as [maven artifact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or on [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (with source code and Javadoc).

**Disclaimer: This library is written and maintained by me**